# mount readable for everyone using udisks-glue

Tags: server, udisks

i'm trying to setup automount solution for usb drives on ubuntu 12.04 Server.
I decided to use udisks with udisks-glue.
Unfortunately when I try to use option user for mounting it fails:

```
udisks --mount /dev/sdb1 --mount-options user
Mount failed: Mount option user is not allowed
```

Without the user option the directory is only readable by root.

I also tried using umask=000 in the options, the dir permission change but still it's empty for the normal user, I can read only while being root. The same problem happens when using udisks from command line as a regular user and from init scripts. only the owner of the directories created changes, but in both situations I can't read as a regular user.

Is it possible to mount using udisks to be readable for everyone?
Best regards
Yemu

Answer (score 0):

If /dev/sdb1 is ntfs filesystem, you should make sure **ntfs-3g** has been installed.
Then just

```
sudo ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 ./yourdir
```

and it can be read/write by all users.